# Animate algorithm

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I want to visualize an algorithm ([Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan)) in python with tkinter.
I want to animate the algorithm and I am stuck.

I basically want to draw and delete lines but I don't understand *canvas.after()* well enough to make it work.

*draw_line()* returns the line object but when I call it in *canvas.after(..., draw_line, ...)* I don't see a way to get the return value or how to call another *canvas.after()* to change the color/delete that line if the function *draw_line()* hasn't been called yet because of the delay.

Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import random


class Point:
    def __init__(self, _x, _y, _a=0):
        self.x = _x
        self.y = _y
        self.angle = _a

    def get_co(self):
        return self.x, self.y


def draw_hull(hull):
    for i in range(len(hull) - 1):
        canvas.create_line(hull[i][0], hull[i][1], hull[i + 1][0], hull[i + 1][1], fill="red", width=2)


def draw_line(p1, p2, color="yellow"):
    return canvas.create_line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, fill=color, width=2)


def convex_hull(list_points):

    # find bottom point
    bottom_point = Point(math.inf, math.inf)
    for point in list_points:
        if point[1] < bottom_point.y:
            bottom_point = Point(point[0], point[1])

    # calculate angles between the bottom point and the other points
    points = []
    for point in list_points:
        if point != bottom_point.get_co():
            new_point = Point(point[0], point[1])
            angle = calculate_angle(bottom_point, new_point)
            new_point.angle = angle
            points.append(new_point)

    # sort the points by angle
    swaps = None
    while swaps != 0:
        swaps = 0
        for i in range(len(points) - 1):
            point1 = points[i]
            point2 = points[i + 1]
            if point1.angle > point2.angle:
                points[i], points[i + 1] = points[i + 1], points[i]
                swaps += 1

    # go through the points and add them to the convex hull
    # if the angle between 3 points ever exeeds 180 degrees, discard the middle point
    hull = [bottom_point, points[0]]

    i = 1
    while i < len(points):
        ####### DRAW LINE #######
        canvas.after(i*500, draw_line, hull[-2], hull[-1])
        ##############

        # check angle
        angle = calculate_angle(hull[-2], hull[-1], points[i])

        if angle == -1:
            ########## DELETE LINE ##########
            # change color of line to red and delete it a bit later
            # canvas.itemconfig(line, fill="red")
            # canvas.after(i*500+250, canvas.delete, line)
            ####################
            # pop the point of the stack
            hull.pop()
        else:
            ########## CHANGE COLOR OF LINE ##########
            # change color of line to green
            # canvas.itemconfig(line, fill="green")
            ####################
            # move to the next point
            hull.append(points[i])
            i += 1

    # add bottom point again for loop
    hull.append(bottom_point)

    # give easy return list (with coordinate-tupels not class objects)
    output = []
    for point in hull:
        output.append(point.get_co())
    return output


def calculate_angle(point1, point2, point3=None):
    if point3 is None:
        if point2.x - point1.x == 0:
            return 90
        elif point2.x - point1.x > 0:
            return math.degrees(math.atan((point2.y - point1.y)/(point2.x - point1.x)))
        else:
            return 180 - math.degrees(math.atan((point2.y - point1.y)/(point1.x - point2.x)))
    else:
        v1 = Point(point1.x - point2.x, point1.y - point2.y)
        v2 = Point(point3.x - point2.x, point3.y - point2.y)
        det = (v1.x * v2.y) - (v2.x * v1.y)

        if det < 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1


window = Tk()

window.geometry("1000x600")
canvas = Canvas(window, width=1000, height=600)
canvas.pack()


POINTSIZE = 2
points = []
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randint(50, 950)
    y = random.randint(50, 550)

    points.append((x, y))
    canvas.create_oval(x - POINTSIZE, y - POINTSIZE, x + POINTSIZE, y + POINTSIZE, fill="black")


hull = convex_hull(points)

# draw_hull(hull)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its true you cant receive return values through `after()` but you can store the value in a list or elsewhere to have access to it. Also consinder using after to call a function within that function to replace the whileloops, since those interrupt the mainloop.

Comment: Well, after the while loop the function returns the completed convex hull so I know how to statically draw that. The thing I want to draw is the changing of the hull as the while loop runs. With 'storing the value in a list' do you mean storing the whole (incomplete) hull at that point in a list and then after the function is done looping over every incomplete hull that the function stored, draw those hulls one after the other, is that the best way to do this?

Comment: As an alternative you could go with threading, but I think the code below does its job quite right. Hope you enjoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have questions about the code, let me know. Because I dont know where to start to explain, since I made major changes to your code.

Anyway, I would be glad if you share your code again, once you are done with, on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and please do let me know. Because it was fun to work with and your code seems incomplete to me.

Happy Coding:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, _x, _y, _a=0):
        self.x = _x
        self.y = _y
        self.angle = _a
        return None
    
    def get_co(self):
        return self.x, self.y

class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,_w,_h):
        super().__init__()
        self.POINTSIZE = 2
        self.points = []
        self.swaps = None
        self.count = 1
        self.delay = 200
        
        self.title('Graham scan simulation')
        
        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self,background='grey')
        self.refresh_button = tk.Button(self.toolbar,text='Refresh',
                                        command=self.refresh)
        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.toolbar,text='Start',
                                      command = self.convex_hull)
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self,width=_w,height=_h)

        self.toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
        self.refresh_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.start_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)

    def generate_points(self):
        for point_instance in self.points:
            yield point_instance

    def find_bottom_point(self):
        bottom_point = Point(math.inf,math.inf)
        for point in self.generate_points():
            if point.y < bottom_point.y:
                bottom_point = point
        return bottom_point

    def calculate_angle(self,point1, point2):
        if point2.x - point1.x == 0:
            return 90
        elif point2.x - point1.x > 0:
            return math.degrees(math.atan((point2.y - point1.y)/(point2.x - point1.x)))
        else:
            return 180 - math.degrees(math.atan((point2.y - point1.y)/(point1.x - point2.x)))
    
    
    def calculate_angels_by_bottom_point(self,bottom_point):
        for point in self.generate_points():
            if point != bottom_point:
                angle = self.calculate_angle(bottom_point,point)
                point.angle = angle

    def sort_points(self,event_variable):        
        if self.swaps != 0:
            self.swaps = 0
            for i in range(len(self.points)-1):
                point1 = self.points[i]
                point2 = self.points[i + 1]
                if point1.angle > point2.angle:
                    self.points[i], self.points[i + 1] = self.points[i + 1], self.points[i]
                    self.swaps += 1
            if self.swaps == 0:
                event_variable.set(1)
            self.after(20,self.sort_points,event_variable)

    def check_angle(self,point1,point2,point3):
        v1 = Point(point1.x - point2.x, point1.y - point2.y)
        v2 = Point(point3.x - point2.x, point3.y - point2.y)
        det = (v1.x * v2.y) - (v2.x * v1.y)
        if det < 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1
    def draw_line(self,p1,p2,color='yellow'):
        return self.canvas.create_line(p1.x,p1.y, p2.x,p2.y, fill='yellow',tags='line')
    def clear_red_lines(self,p1,p2):
        shapes = self.canvas.find_withtag('line')
        for shape in shapes:
            if self.canvas.itemcget(shape,'fill') == 'red':
                coords = self.canvas.coords(shape)
                overlapped = self.canvas.find_overlapping(*coords)
                for i in overlapped:
                    coords2 = self.canvas.coords(i)
                    if coords == coords2:
                        self.canvas.delete(i)
                self.canvas.delete(shape)
    def animated_draw(self,hull):
        if self.count != len(self.points):
            line = self.draw_line(hull[-2],hull[-1])
            check_mark = self.check_angle(hull[-2],hull[-1],self.points[self.count])
            if check_mark == -1:
                self.canvas.itemconfig(line,fill='red')
                self.after(self.delay-100,lambda:self.clear_red_lines(hull[-2],hull[-1]))
                hull.pop()
            else:
                self.canvas.itemconfig(line,fill='green')
                hull.append(self.points[self.count])
                self.count += 1
            self.after(self.delay,self.animated_draw,hull)
    def convex_hull(self):
        bottom_point = self.find_bottom_point()
        self.calculate_angels_by_bottom_point(bottom_point)
        event_variable = tk.IntVar(self,value=0)
        self.sort_points(event_variable)
        self.wait_variable(event_variable)
        self.points.pop(0)
        self.animated_draw(hull = [bottom_point, self.points[0]])

    def generate_listpoints(self,_amount):
        '''using a generator for memory purpose'''
        for i in range(_amount):
            x = random.randint(50, 950)
            y = random.randint(50, 550)
            yield x,y
    def refresh(self):
        self.swaps = None
        self.count = 1
        self.points= []
        self.populate_canvas()
    def populate_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.delete('all')
        for x,y in self.generate_listpoints(100):
            self.points.append(Point(x, y))#instead of creating throwing instances away.
            self.canvas.create_oval(x - self.POINTSIZE,
                                    y - self.POINTSIZE,
                                    x + self.POINTSIZE,
                                    y + self.POINTSIZE,
                                    fill="black")
root = Window(1000,600)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow this is great! It is clear to me now that my code lacks a lot of structure. The problem is that if I just copy-paste your code in a .py file it doesn't seem to do anything with exit code 0. I tried finding the problem myself but I don't understand everything you have written. The debugger stops at the 'super().__init__()

Comment: @Yoekek This code was written with python3.7. Do you have an older version that doesn't support super or super needs additional arguments? Anyway, try `tk.Tk.__init__(self)` instead. I'm currently not on a machine. At Friday I will have some time left left.

Comment: I have python 3.9. You're suggestion also didn't work. I would appreciate it if you try to sort out my problem but feel no obligation to do so, I will try to implement idea's of your code in my own but without just copying lines since that isn't my goal.

Comment: @Yoekek Did you notice that my import expression is different from yours? While you copy and paste the code, did you also copy the imports? Also have you copied the last logical line where I create an instance of Window? In addition it may needed to change it to `Window(1000,600).mainloop()`.